# Proof of a modified Bayes' theorem

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I know this question is not very hard to answer,  but it posed as a problem for me, so it may pose as a problem to other people too.

---

We know that [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) is stated using the following formula:
$$Pr(A\big | B) = \frac{Pr(B \big | A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$$
Where $A$ and $B$ are events and $Pr(B) \neq 0$.
Now, in [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf) by James et al. it is given that

> Bayes' Theorem states that $$Pr(Y=k | X=x) =
>  \frac{\pi_kf_k(x)}{\sum_{l=1}^K\pi_lf_l(x)}$$

Where $\pi_k$ is the fraction of the training observations that belong to the $k$ th class, and $f_k(x)$ is the *density function* which is equivalent to $Pr(X=x|Y=k)$.
How are the two formulas related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given, $\pi_k$ is simply the probability that $Y=k$. And it is already given that $f_k(x)=Pr(X=x|Y=k)$. So, the numerators of both the formulas correspond to each other correctly. Now here comes the denominator:  (let $K$ denote the total number of classes that $Y$ can take)
$$ \sum_{l=1}^K\pi_lf_l(x) = \sum_{l=1}^KPr(Y=l)\times Pr(X=x|Y=l)
\\ = \sum_{l=1}^KPr(X=x)\times Pr(Y=l|X=x)
\\ = Pr(X=x)\times\sum_{l=1}^KPr(Y=l|X=x)
\\ = Pr(X=x)\times 1
\\ = Pr(X=x)$$

Answer (score 0):

A shorter and maybe more intuitive way to answer this:

Let's say K=2, with classes $K_1$ and $K_2$. Remember that according to the Bayes theorem $Pr(A, B) = Pr(B \big | A)Pr(A)$.

We can then write the sum as:

$$\sum_{l=1}^K\pi_lf_l(x)=\pi_1f_1(x)+\pi_2f_2(x)$$

Using Bayes:
$$ = Pr(k=1, X=x) + Pr(k=2, X=x) $$

$$ = Pr(X=x)$$